# How to add to a ASP.NET Core (.NET6) project OWASP recommendation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, owasp

I am creating a new ASP.NET Core project with .NET6. I have a UI project that calls the API project. Fonts are coming from Google and the avatar from Gravatar.

In the `Program.cs` I added those lines

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
        new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            MustRevalidate = true,
            NoCache = true,
            NoStore = true,

        };

    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
        "base-uri 'self'; " +
        "connect-src 'self' localhost:44381 localhost:44399 localhost:59145 api-portal-dev.mysite.com; " +
        "form-action 'self'; " +
        "font-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com https://www.gravatar.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; " +
        "frame-ancestors 'none'; " +
        "img-src https:;");

    return next.Invoke();
});
```

[image]

If I run the test with the [OWASP Zap](https://www.zaproxy.org/download/), I have a lot of alerts.

| Alert type | Risk | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CSP: Wildcard Directive | Medium | 3 (30.0%) |
| Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens | Low | 2 (20.0%) |
| Cookie with SameSite Attribute None | Low | 2 (20.0%) |
| Cookie without SameSite Attribute | Low | 1 (10.0%) |
| Incomplete or No Cache-control Header Set | Low | 3 (30.0%) |
| Server Leaks Information via "X-Powered-By" HTTP Response Header Field(s) | Low | 1 (10.0%) |
| Timestamp Disclosure - Unix | Low | 9 (90.0%) |
| CSP: X-Content-Security-Policy | Informational | 1 (10.0%) |
| Information Disclosure - Suspicious Comments | Informational | 13 (130.0%) |
| Loosely Scoped Cookie | Informational | 3 (30.0%) |
| Total |  | 10 |

How can I fix them?

Comment: Here a tutorial how to improve the security of Blazor WebAssemply or ASP.NET Core web applications https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/blazor/add-security-headers-to-blazor-webassembly/