# Blazor with .NET6 add Response Headers

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, owasp

I'm trying to sort out the [OWASP recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209211/how-to-add-to-a-asp-net-core-net6-project-owasp-recommendation) in my Blazor Web Assembly project.

Usually, in other .NET Core projects I added this code

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
        new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            MustRevalidate = true,
            NoCache = true,
            NoStore = true,

        };

    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", 
        "default-src 'none'; " + "script-src 'self'; " + 
        "connect-src 'self'; " + 
        "img-src 'self'; " + 
        "style-src 'self'; " +
        "base-uri 'self'; " + 
        "form-action 'self'; " + 
        "frame-ancestors 'none';");

    return next.Invoke();
});
```

The first problem is `app.Use()` doesn't exists. Also, if I run the OWASP tool, I have a quite long list of issues.

[image]

[image]

How can I configure all the OWASP recommendations in my application?

Comment: That would have nothing to do with your blazor webassembly project - as that runs in the browser. Your headers would come from the host serving up the application.

Answer (score 0):

I could not make a standalone blazor wasm (client side / not hosted with .net core mvc/api apps) to include response headers to allow cors to another host BUT i was able to do this by hosting the blazor wasm on iis and use this iis feature to add response headers to every request, so when the wasm app files are loaded into the browser, the browses will receive these headers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/development/add-http-response-header-web-site

I made IIS to add the cors header to the http response

```
access-control-allow-origin
```

I set it to my server's / api's origin
I could not find any information on doing this anywhere and I still have to way to add cors headers from inside the wasm client (decoupled app) itself

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Late Reply, but maybe it still helps :)

In my Blazor Server Apps if I only want to apply it for certain Sites I do it by injecting the IHttpContextAccessor.

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _hca
```

// your page in between

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _hca.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", $"frame-ancestors SAMPLE.COM");
}
```

Happy coding!

EDIT:
As stated correctly by Marvin this is not a recommended approach

Comment: It is not recommended to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` in Blazor Server apps since it cannot be guranteed if it is set. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#avoid-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components